# Excel Power Query - Merge cells in only one column and keep other columns the same

Tags: excel

I have a table containing the following columns:
name, charge code ID, charge code name and hours. This table provides an overview of how many hours a certain person booked an a certain charge code. However, it could happen that a person books on two different charge codes - then this person appears twice in the table.

The goal would be to merge the duplicate names in the name column, but keep the information about the charge codes and hours booked on the different charge codes. Also, as the last table of the column, I would like to add a sum of the total hours of one person. I tried these steps with excel power query group by. However I receive the following output:

[image]

--> As can be seen in the screenshot, names and sums of hours in case of a person charging on two different charge codes appear twice. Any help on how to solve this, would be really appreciated. (I don’t want to work with a pivot table)

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a data sample **as text which can be copy/pasted** that shows the problem, along with a screenshot of your desired output from that data.

Comment: If you can add in your existing DAX, that would help, too. What your asking sounds completely possible (and common) using Power Query.

Comment: I added a screenshot for further context - does this help?